# CrystalReport and SQL Server : connection error

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

We have an inhouse system that creates a report with Cyrstal Report using data from SQL Server. Unfortunately the person who created the software already left. The new user of the computer installed another version of Crystal Report on that computer and after that he can not generate reports.

We are getting errors:

> 20536 Error in File: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.

then

> 20599 Cannot open SQL Server.

Looks like the connection from Crystal Report to SQL Server has been reset or something. I'm not familiar with Crystal Report and SQL Server, but I can understand some codes and how it works. Can someone please help me with this?
I can assure that the software is connecting to SQL Server but not with Crystal Report to SQL Server. We can also connect manually using username and password in SQL Server.

We are using Windows 10 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. The server is his own workstation and hes only the one using it.